# How do you hide a Powershell progress message?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

I think [Write-Progress](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347663.aspx) is a rather beautiful Cmdlet. In fact Sharepoint makes use of it with its [Start-SPAdminJob](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607833.aspx) commandlet.

All fine and dandy, the problem is that Start-SPAdminJob does not correctly "dispose" of the Write-Progress dialog. It is never set to 100 percent complete which means it just stays in the Powershell dialog until you exit the script - this in turn hides part of the messages underneath the "progress window".

Is there any way I can force an existing `Write-Progress` to "exit" or be set to 100% complete? Any way how I could find out the ID of the progress the `Start-SPAdminJob` cmdlet is using - that way I could manually set the percentage.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could stop the progress bar appearing in the first place by doing the following beforehand:

```
$ProgressPreference = "SilentlyContinue";
```

You could then restore the preference to "Continue" afterwards. Not much help if you actually want the bar of course...

Comment: Care to enlighten me how you know about this magic? Didn't know I can just set ProgressPreference... Are there more secret switches? :)

Comment: @moontear look at `Get-Variable *preference` It will list all the preference variables.

Comment: even better: get-help about_preference_variables

Comment: even better: get-help about_automatic_variable

Comment: even betterer: `Get-Help *|Get-Help |more`. There, now you know everything ;-)

Comment: I love the betterments! Thx guys

Comment: what blew my mind was that outputting the value of $ProgressPreference at the beginning of the script showed "SilentlyContinue" but I still got the information bar, but then adding the line $ProgressPreference = "SilentlyContinue" DID hide the bar. Must be some weird scope related complexity, but I am now happy.

Answer (score 7):

This code forces progress bar to be set to 100% complete and hides it:

```
Write-Progress "Done" "Done" -completed
```

Comment: it does if I was the one starting the progress bar - this question was a special were a third party started a progress bar and i needed to close it somehow