# Powershell - remove "API running..."

Tags: powershell

I'm new to Powershell scripting. i'm writing a script to automate some Dell EqualLogic storage array functions using the EqualLogic cmdlets.

When my script is running, it keeps overlaying "PSAPI.Cmdlets.xxxxx started...", "PSAPI.Cmdlets.xxxxxx Finished" over the top of whatever my script is outputting so you can't see it.

Anyone know how I can prevent this? Image of what I mean here:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at the output of `Write-Progress` and it *may* be [possible to suppress it](https://www.google.com/search?q=powershell+suppress+write-progress). But a better route would be to find some way through the cmdlets to turn it off via their options. Dell doesn't make the documentation freely available so you'll have to look at it yourself.

You might also want to write your messages to a logfile.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651120/how-do-you-hide-a-powershell-progress-message